# Typescript ignoring the fs.d.ts definition for MakeDirectoryOptions

Tags: node.js, typescript

Why won't this compile?

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
var folder: string = "c:/test1/test2/test3/";
fs.mkdirSync(folder, { recursive:true }); // the {object} shows an error
```

I am a TypeScript newbie using MS Visual Studio 2019 Community. Converting working Node.JS code to TypeScript. I am calling a function at project startup. This code works in Node.JS but shows a compile error in TypeScript.

fs.mkdirSync(folder, { recursive: true }); // the {object} won't compile.

I cannot see why I am not allowed to pass an object specifying the recursive bit. Currently wandering in the newbie wilderness. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
When I hover over the compile error I get this pop-up:

```
(property) recursive: boolean

(TS) Argument of type '{ recursive: boolean }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'. 
Type '{ recursive: boolean }' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

it seems to be ignoring the fs.d.ts definition for MakeDirectoryOptions:

What I did so far:

1) I have searched drive C: and found 4 fs.d.ts files. Each contains the following definitions:

```
function mkdirSync(path: PathLike, options?: number | string | MakeDirectoryOptions | null): void;

export interface MakeDirectoryOptions {
        /**
         * Indicates whether parent folders should be created.
         * @default false
         */
        recursive?: boolean;
        /**
         * A file mode. If a string is passed, it is parsed as an octal integer. If not specified
         * @default 0o777.
         */
        mode?: number;
    }
```

2) I have tried tinkering with the package.json settings:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.14",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2" // forcing this to use the latest 3.6.0
  }
```

Code to reproduce the problem:
-----server.ts

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
//import fs = require("fs"); // does not work
//var fs = require("fs"); // compiles   

var folder:string = "c:/test1/test2/test3/";
var result: string = "untested";
try {
    // test for the existance of a folder 
    if (!fs.existsSync(folder)) {
        // create the folder if found to not exist
        fs.mkdirSync(folder, { recursive: true }); // { recursive: true } shows as compile error
        result = "created";
    }
    else {
        result = "exists already";
    }
}catch(err) {
    result = err.message;
}

import * as http from 'http';
var port: number | string = process.env.port || 1337
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('Operation result: = ' + result + "\n");

}).listen(port);
```

-----package.json

```
{
  "name": "trials",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "trials",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build",
    "clean": "tsc --build --clean"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.14",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  }
}
```

-----tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

-----end of code

If I change the "import * as fs from 'fs';" line to:
var fs = require("fs");
Everything compiles and works - but I think that is cheating?

it seems to be ignoring the fs.d.ts definition for MakeDirectoryOptions:

function mkdirSync(path: PathLike, options?: number | string | MakeDirectoryOptions | null): void;

export interface MakeDirectoryOptions {etc....}

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34980

The answer above is still confusing for TypeScript newbies so I did a global uninstall of the types and reinstall the latest version. I opened a command prompt as Admin and typed as follows.

```
npm uninstall -g @types/node 
npm install -g @types/node@latest
```

This seems to have fix the problem. Please advise if you suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was fixed when I downgrade the @types/node version

```
    "@types/node": "16.0.0"
```

to

```
    "@types/node": "15.12.5"
```